# COUNT multiple values from one column in the database and then split into different columns in my table

Tags: c#, sql

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to count multiple values from one column in my SQL Database and then show results in my DataGrid Table.

**Here is my Table**

[image]

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="User" Binding="{Binding UserName}" Width="200"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Jobs Booked" Binding="{Binding JobsCount}" Width="200"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Plumbing" Binding="{Binding PlumbingCount}" Width="200"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Drainage" Binding="{Binding DrainsCount}" Width="200"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

**Here is my current query trying to show plumbing count**

```
    string query = @"
SELECT
  COUNT(ID) AS JobsCount,
  UserName,
  COUNT(JobType) As PlumbingCount
FROM tblJobs
WHERE JobType = 'Plumbing'
 AND CAST(CreatedOn AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
Group by UserName
ORDER BY COUNT(ID) DESC
";
```

In my database, Total is;

Dan - Username

4 - Total Jobs Booked

3 - Plumbing

1 - Drainage

My current query is only showing total jobs for plumbing.

I need table to show the relevant count based on if its plumbing or drainage which show in same column in my database under **'JobType'** and then total jobs for that user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It looks like you need conditional aggregation here.** You do this by placing `CASE` inside an aggregation.

Further points:

- `COUNT(something)` just counts every non-null value, it does not count unique values. For that you need `COUNT(DISTINCT something)`
- `CAST(CreatedOn AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` is not easy for the server to optimize, it's much better to give an explicit begin and end range

```sql
SELECT
  UserName,
  COUNT(*) AS JobsCount,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN JobType = 'Plumbing' THEN 1 END) As PlumbingCount,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN JobType = 'Drainage' THEN 1 END) As DrainageCount
FROM tblJobs
WHERE 
 AND CreatedOn >= CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)
 AND CreatedOn < CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) AS datetime)
GROUP BY UserName
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: Nice one, thanks for the tip on the DATE  Cast, I really need to brush up!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `PIVOT`.  The `PIVOT` clause creates named columns from expected data within a given `SELECT` structure.  This has the same output of a simple cross-tab query, but with some flexibility to do even more detailed analysis.

It looks like you need to use a `PIVOT` like this:

```
SELECT username, 
jobtotal = SUM([plumbing]+[drainage]), 
[plumbing], 
[drainage] 
FROM
 (
   SELECT 
   username, 
   1 AS jobcount,
   jobtype
   FROM jobs
   WHERE createdon >= CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime) 
 AND created < CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) AS datetime)
 ) ps
PIVOT
(
  SUM(jobcount)
  FOR jobtype IN ([plumbing], [drainage])
  ) AS pvt 
 GROUP BY username, [plumbing], [drainage]
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0aef98/8

Comment: Thank you! Both answers given were great, CharlieFace answer was just a bit easier on the eyes for me haha